# What is the relation between the two verbs 思われる and 思う?

Tags: verbs

If 思われる is "its own verb," meaning "to seem;  to appear," and is independent of the separate verb 思う, meaning "to think," is there a conceptual relation between the two? I ask because I initially thought 思われる to be the passive form of 思う. Would it be wrong to think of 思われる meaning "it is thought" rather than "it seems"?

> 意外に思われるかもしれません。
>   This may surprise you.
>
> このことは、私たちにはとても不思議に思われる。
>   This appears very strange to us.
>
> そのようなプロジェクトを経た後では、すべてがはるかにたやすいように思われる。
>   Having come from something like the project, it seems like everything is a lot easier.
>
> それは私には奇妙に思われる。
>   It seems strange to me.
>
> 彼女はとても年をとっているように思われる。
>   She seems (to me) (to be) a very old woman.

Comment: @snailplane, I should have consulted some japanese dictionaries but on tangorin they provided a separate entry with conjugation, where i found this gem- "思われられる". http://tangorin.com/general/思われる

Comment: 「自発」の「思われる」ですよね。The passive is 思われる, the honorific is also 思われる, the potential is 思える, and... what is 思われられる? The passive 思われる + the honorific れる (ie. 思われていらっしゃる), or the passive 思われる + the potential れる (ie. 思われることができる), maybe?

Comment: @Chocolate, do you mean spontaneous when you say 自発?

Comment: @yadokari それです^^ （文法用語はよく分からないのですが。。たぶん）

Comment: @Chocolate, someone gave me this example, but i dont know how to translate it: 彼にすごく、思われられて（＝思われて）、困っているの。

Comment: おもわれられる・・・？ううむ・・・？「彼にすごく好かれて困ってる」って意味ですよね・・ふつう、「思われる」ですよねぇ・・ww

Comment: maybe= he's so obsessed with me that it's annoying.

he's so into me that it's annoying.

Comment: ここにも「おもわれられる」がありました。（あってるのかなぁ・・わかりません）　http://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=29580&element_id=40584&conjugation_type_id=15

Comment: Listing 思われる as a verb of its own seems strange to me, since this "spontaneous"-derivation has productivity, consider 感じられる, 推定される etc. And 思われられる definitely seems non-standard to me, an "automatic-verb-conjugator" effect of listing 思われる by itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been thinking about various different sentences that include 思われる to see if any of them feel like a distinctive word of its own, and my feeling is that the answer is no.

思う does mean "to think", as in "明日は雨だと思う / I think it'll rain tomorrow", and thus its passive form 思われる means "it is thought". The passiveness would be amplified when it is used without a specific subject, making it ambiguous as to who is thinking. Doing this creates a sense that the thought is shared by many/all/everyone, as in "情勢は不利だと思われる / the situation does not appear good." It makes the sentence feel more objective, and I think this is the effect that's making you feel that it has a separate meaning.

In contrast, when 思われる is used with a specific subject, it's easy to see that it's the passive form of 思う. This is true even when the subject is implied, as in "バカだと思われるよ / [he will] think you are stupid."

Note that 思われる is also a polite form (尊敬語) of 思う, as in "どう思われますか？ / What do you think?". The example of "意外に思われるかもしれません" that you cited is also this usage.

Comment: thank you. Do you have an opinion on "思われられる" as is discussed in the comments below the question above?