# Interpretation of 思われる (spontaneous or passive?)

Tags: grammar

My understanding is that 思われる, in addition to being the passive form of 思う, can also be used in the sense of "to spontaneously think; to appear".

> 北米では通常スカートは女性がはくものと思われている。
>   In North America a skirt is thought of as something a woman wears.

In which sense is 思われる being used here? Both seem reasonable:
Spontaneous: In North America, people spontaneously think a skirt is something a woman wears.
Passive: A skirt is thought of by North Americans as something a woman wears.

I lean more towards the first one, since a passive sentence would normally mark the agent with に i.e.

> スカートは北米人には女性がはくものと思われている。

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11534/what-is-the-relation-between-the-two-verbs-%E6%80%9D%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-and-%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86

Comment: What source is your "spontaneous" meaning from?

Comment: @yadokari I believe it's one of the four uses of （ら）れる identified in traditional grammar, called [自発](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E7%99%BA_%28%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%29).  The other three are 受身 (passive), 尊敬 (honorific), and 可能 (potential).

Comment: @yadokari My source was the entry for 思われう in A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar, which describes it as "a verb that indicates what the speaker/writer feels spontaneously". They also explicitly distinguish this usage from the passive form of 思う.

Comment: Somehow, I don't think the ている form can be the spontaneous kind, and I think the reason could be related to this question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6538/%E6%80%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-%E8%A8%80%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-with-third-person-subject .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your last comment (emphasis added):

> a verb that indicates what the **speaker/writer** feels spontaneously

This does not match the translation you give for "spontaneous:"

> In North America, **people** spontaneously think a skirt is something a woman wears.

Do you see the difference? If `思われる` were supposed to indicate the *author's* thoughts or feelings, a better translation would be

> It seems that in North America skirts are usually worn by women.

However, with no other context, there is nothing to indicate that this is a personal observation of the author, so the translation

> In North America a skirt is thought of as something a woman wears.

seems most appropriate to me.

Also note that it is quite common to leave out the agent in passive sentences. Just a few examples:

> 今日学校でいじめられた。
>   I got bullied at school today.
>
> 政府は倒された。
>   The government was overthrown.
>
> 彼は殺された。
>   He was killed.

Answer (score 4):

The 自発 (spontaneous) 思われる is a static verb (like いる and ある) and cannot take the ている form. So the 思われている in the example is definitely a passive.

The passive 思われる can take the 思われている form based on tense/aspect.

Comment: That is the grammatical explanation that I was searching for but couldn't find. This is a better answer.